# how to pass drawable image to MediaMetadata in chromecast

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nativescript, chromecast

I'm integrating chromecast into my application. when i'm building media info

```
private fun buildMediaInfo(video_url: String?): MediaInfo? {
        try {
            val movieMetadata = MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE)
            movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, sub_title)
            movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, title)
            if (image_url != null) {
                movieMetadata.addImage(WebImage(Uri.parse(getSignedUrl(image_url))));
            } else { 
             ...
             // need to implement
             ...
            }
.....
.....
.....

}
```

- here for so many videos thumbnail was not there in server.
- So, when there is no thumbnail, inside else condition i need to display default image from drawabe(`R.drawable.play_movie_card_no_film`).

i tried something like below but it is not working

```
val img_uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://${context!!.packageName.toString()}/drawable/play_movie_card_no_film");
movieMetadata.addImage(WebImage(img_uri))
```

anyone know how to set local image into `movieMetadata` while integrating `chromecast`

Comment: have you found any solution ?